# How is the URL routing handled in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url-routing

I am trying to understand how URL dispatching in Wordpress backend occurs? I asked a related question: [How to find php file or function that generates a wordpress admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623030/how-to-find-php-file-or-function-that-generates-a-wordpress-admin-page/13623354#13623354)

One answer said that I need to search in the code for some unique text that is rendered in the output. I was expecting some logical mechanism such as the url dispatching or routing mechanism in Rails or Django. Isn't there a similar mechanism in Wordpress?

Comment: Are you talking about front office (i.e. wordpress themes), or backoffice (wp-admin) ?